# How to display Hebrew text in html title and in body correctly in a simple way

Tags: html, title, hebrew, liveserver

How to display Hebrew text in  html title and in body correctly in a simple way

When I open it in VSCode Live View option it shows symbols instead Hebrew characters in a title and in body of web page.

what should I do to see Hebrew text correctly?

[image: the web page capture here]

The index.html file contains:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>שלום</title>
  </head>
  <body lang="he" dir="rtl">
    <h1>שלום עולם!</h1>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to see in title

```
שלום
```

and in body

```
שלום עולם!
```

The response content in chrome browser:

[image: the response content in chrome browser capture]

Response header doesn't contain any Content-Type.
How  Content-Type can be defined?
[image: Response Headers]

Comment: you need to add a Hebrew font

Comment: That title works fine here in chrome, without loading any extra fonts

Comment: Go inspect the request using your browser dev tools, and see if there is a `Content-Type` response header, that indicates a different charset than UTF-8, perhaps. HTTP headers have priority over their meta element "counterparts."

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, the Response tab also cant display Hebrew fonts. I suspect problem with VSCode editor definitions or html file encoding. but cant identify the solution yet

Comment: _"the Response tab also cant display Hebrew fonts."_ - that isn't what I asked you to check.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't contain any Content-Type.

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Update File encoding in VSCode editor]

this solution worked for me "change-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-code"

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether. [answer]. If your question is a duplicate of that answer, you should delete this one.

Comment: I understand Rob, but the question was completely different and a same solution worked for this question too ...